# CurrentDb.RecordsAffected returns 0. Why?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, dao

If I use RecordsAffected with CurrentDb.Execute, it always returns 0. If I first make a instance of a Database object it works properly. Why?

Like this:

```
Dim Db As Database
Set Db = CurrentDb

Db.Execute "DELETE * FROM [Samples] WHERE Sample=5"
If Db.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

Instead of:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [Samples] WHERE Sample=5"
If CurrentDb.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

I'm using Access 2007 and the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Objects Library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each time you use CurrentDB, it is a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `With`.  Change your code to:

```
Dim Db As Database
Dim recordAffect = Integer
Set Db = CurrentDb
With Db
  .Execute "DELETE * FROM [Samples] WHERE Sample=5"
  recordAffect = .RecordsAffected
  'If Db.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
  If (recordAffect = 0)  Then
     MsgBox "Error"
  End If
End With
```