# How do I convert this SQL Server Insert statment to be useable in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

Access has a problem with both the sub queries but when i run them separately they work fine

```
Insert INTO tblFeedbackJoin (
   FeedbackID,
   ProductID,BrokerID,
   VendorID
)  Values( 
   SELECT MAX(FeedbackID) From tblfeedback , 
   NULL , 
   SELECT BrokerID From tblBroker WHERE bName = 'ABC Broker' , 
   NULL
)
```

Have also tried encapsulating the sub-queries in parenthesis.. to no avail..

Can this be done in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use subqueries in this case, try domain aggregate functions.

```
INSERT INTO tblfeedbackjoin
            (feedbackid,
             productid,
             brokerid,
             vendorid)
VALUES      ( DMax("feedbackid","tblfeedback"),
            NULL,
            Dlookup("brokerid", "tblbroker", "bname = 'ABC Broker'"),
            NULL)
```

I would be very nervous indeed about Max in a multi-user database.

Comment: Yeah the MAX is to get the autonumber that was generated from a previous command. this is tryign to insert into a join table to keep the database in 3rd normal form.  I do agree it looks weird but i can't use @@identity as the previous connection is completely closed by the time this runs.  I'll try this out.

Comment: Why close the connection?

Comment: Thank you very much, not only for a working answer but also giving the name "domain aggregate functions" We never went over those in class and i can see my self useing those everywhere!

Comment: Thank you for you confidence! Please be careful with domain aggregate functions, they can be slow, and are only relevant to MS Access.

Comment: When I try to keep a connection open I tend to get blank results from subsequent queries...(but only sometimes) It got so bad that I wrote a class that just gets the data, puts it in a reader and shuts the connection.  I then have all the time in the world to work with the data and do what I need.  I'm sure there is a better way.  <omitting long rant about Access>  When I'm afforded down time I'll try looking into it again. Thank you very much again.

Comment: If your are working within MS Access, create a new instance of the db (Set db = CurrentDB), this will give you much more control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004153/currentdb-recordsaffected-returns-0-why/3004536#3004536, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute/11213943#11213943 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301967/how-to-get-last-inserted-row-identity-in-a-table-of-ms-access/12302038#12302038

Comment: Seems I forgot a tag. This is going to be used in a VB.Net program as part of my Project Development class.  Had to use Access so the teacher could check the work.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised this works in SQL Server, as it is not valid SQL. You can either use `VALUES` or `SELECT` in an `INSERT`, but not both.

```
Insert INTO tblFeedbackJoin (FeedbackID,ProductID,BrokerID,VendorID)
SELECT MAX(tblfeedback.FeedbackID), NULL, tblBroker.BrokerID , NULL
 From tblfeedback, tblBroker
 WHERE tblBroker.bName = 'ABC Broker'
GROUP BY tblBroker.BrokerID
```

is valid SQL.

Comment: apparently Access does not use teh cross join key words but will use the implict cross join Fixing the code.

Comment: SQL is generic, it does not refer to SQL Server.

Comment: @Remou I mentioned SQL Server as the question title says "How do I convert this SQL Server Insert statment to be useable in Access".

Comment: nice i need to keep this in mind also. I was under the impression that without the Values keyword, the Insert would break.  I orginally had the subqueries hiding in thier own ()'s but then Access would tell me i was missing tables or queries..